# How to import component correctly in React.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this project structure

[image]

Sorry for question, I am new in React, I can't uderstand how I should call this code in **ol-map.js**

```
import React from "react";

import {
  Map,
  layer,
  Layers
} from "react-openlayers";

class olMap extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="Map">
        <Map view={{ center: [0, 0], zoom: 2 }}>
          <Layers>
            <layer.Tile />
          </Layers>
        </Map>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default olMap;
```

**in my Map.js page?**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import olMap from '../components/map/ol-test3/ol-map';

class Map extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
          <olMap/>
        );
    }
}

export default Map;
```

P.S. This is **index.js** file and I have no idea why I need it.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import olMap from "./ol-map";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <olMap />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  rootElement
);
```

Comment: What did you try so far about the imports ? Did you check any documentation about ReactDOM or module imports before coming here ?

Comment: React components should be named with capitals, e.g. `OLMap.js`, `<OLMap/>`

Answer (score 1):

In your component .js, make sure you have

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
class OLMap extends Component {
```

And then

```
import OLMap from "./OLMap";
```

And of course check your folder structure

Answer (score 1):

```
import OLMap from "../map/ol-test3/ol-map"
```

Name does not matter in *default export* so you can name whatever you want while importing.

Comment: even though there is no map on my page

Comment: Then there would be some thing wrong in `olMap`, as per your project structure and query, importing would fine.